# Detect host's name

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, hostname

Is it possible to somehow fetch the hostname where a website/service resides? I've tried looking into headers, and some more info, but from what I've seen it doesn't seem possible!

As an example: `test.mysite.com` to be the host's name in `/etc/hostname`

If it turns to be possible, how can I hide it?

The linux distribution that I use is Debian 6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're question seems to be about whether other people can see your host's name if you are running a publicly visible Web server on it.  No, they only see the name you have published in the [Domain Name System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) for your public IP address.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `hostname` to whatever you want as long you alter other configuration files along with the change.

As far as I know, there is no direct way of fetching the hostname of the computer unless there is a DNS entry pointing to the IP address with that hostname. However, some servers might have an API method or a procedure call which makes them get and print/send the hostname.